# Json Decode returning NULL

Tags: php, json

I am trying to decode json into array in PHP.But My json is like

```
string(307) " string(290) "{"id":"1","name":"test name","rowno":"0","note":"test notes","created_date":"2016-05-01","updated_date":"2016-05-12 05:08:05"}" "
```

string within a string!!
How to convert it into array.

Comment: This is a `var_dump()` of the `json`. Where is this json being produced? Show the code that generates it.

Comment: Where are getting the `string(307) " string(290)` from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like you're trying to decode (*or trying to output*) the data with `var_dump()`. That isn't the function you require; what you require is [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode):

```
$data = json_decode($json);
```

---

If that isn't the issue, and you're actually receiving the data as above then you'll have to strip it out - most likely using a regex like the following:

```
$s = 'string(307) " string(290) "{"id":"1","name":"test name","rowno":"0","note":"test notes","created_date":"2016-05-01","updated_date":"2016-05-12 05:08:05"}" "';

preg_match('/\{(.*)\}/', $s, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Which would return your `json`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => {"id":"1","name":"test name","rowno":"0","note":"test notes","created_date":"2016-05-01","updated_date":"2016-05-12 05:08:05"}
    [1] => "id":"1","name":"test name","rowno":"0","note":"test notes","created_date":"2016-05-01","updated_date":"2016-05-12 05:08:05"
)
```

Thus allowing you to decode it properly within `$matches`.

Regex is a beast to me so I'll try explain as best as possible what the expression is doing:

- `\{` matches the first open `{`
- `(.*)` matches any character inbetween
- `\}` matches the closing `}`

Comment: Yes you are right.The problem is am using var_dump() instead of echo.I changed it and it is working fine.Thank you :-)

Comment: After a lot RND, this is the answer which work for me and making sans.